# Android MCC and MNC

Tags: android, gsm, mobile-country-code

I'm trying to get the `mcc` and `mnc` after a `SIM LOADED` state, in order to check if the SIM card did change without `READ PHONE STATE` permissions, in order to disable the app requests for some networks and in some countries that the user do not want.

Since `getSimOperator()` may change according to the current carrier (e.g. when the user is on roaming or not) I decided to use the `getNetworkOperator()`.

Although this method can return `null` even if the `SIM` is `LOADED` and may return different results e.g. a lycamobile card with GSM only connection is giving me `mnc = 01` and when I take the SIM card out and put it again it gives me `mnc = 04`.

**Does some one know why the mnc gives different results for the `getNetworkOperator()`? Which method is better, `getNetworkOperator()` or `getSimOperator()` for this case?**

Also, I cannot use `getResources().getConfiguration().mcc` because it gives a int number which might remove the `0` before e.g. gives `4` instead of `04`.

This is my code to check a SIM state change:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
            String ss = extras.getString(EXTRAS_SIM_STATUS);
            if (ss != null && (ss.equals("LOADED"))) {
                TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && hasPermissions(READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
                   //here I get the imsi
                }else{
                   L.d("NetworkOperator result %s", telephonyManager.getNetworkOperator()); 
                   //saving in shared preferences in order to check if the sim is allowed or not
                   //this is also called on application onCreate() so I can check the current SIM
               }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

PS: the SIM card that I'm using only has GSM connection. Also I tried with an other card (with 4g capabilities) and everything works as expected the `mnc` is the same `01` for a vodafone card.

Comment: I think you have this: `Since getSimOperator() may change according to the current carrier (e.g. when the user is on roaming or not) I decided to use the getNetworkOperator().` backwards.  getSimOperator should change with the SIM -- but not when roaming, etc.

Comment: I though it was the other way around, going to test on the emulator and I will get back to you then, thanks ;)

Comment: Thanks, it was what you were saying, getSimOperator() comes from the simcard

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Let me share some information with you.. It may help.

**MCC, MNC, PLMN**

First, you must understand MCC and MNC:

> **MCC - Mobile Country Code**
>   This is the country code. It always has 3 digits. Some countries can use more than one MCC.
>
> **MNC - Mobile Network Code**
>   This is the network code. It can have 2 or 3 digits.
>
> **MCCMNC** - PLMN Number.

Those numbers are used to differentiate one carrier from another one.

For example, you can check a list at [www.mcc-mnc.com](http://www.mcc-mnc.com/):

AT&T in US has following PLMN Number:

```
MCC = 310
MNC = 410
PLMN = 310410
```

Telefonica in Brazil, for example, has following PLMN Number:

```
MCC = 724
MNC = 10
PLMN = 72410
```

Based on the information above, we can imagine that we have PLMNs with 5 or 6 digits.

Since MNC can have 2 or 3 digits, I think you can retrieve the MNC number as follows (knowing that MCC always have 3 digits):

```
String plmn = "33402"; // OR 334020
String mcc = plmn.substring(0,3);
String mnc = plmn.substring(3,plmn.length());
System.out.println("plmn[" + plmn + "] mcc[" + mcc + "] mnc[" + mnc + "]");
```

All carriers in same country share the same MCC numbers. Some countries has more than one MCC... But even then, all carriers in that country uses one of that MCC.

So, if you want to check the location of some carrier, you must read its MCC (and never its MNC).

**SIM and Network**

One information stored in the simcard is that PLMN number. The PLMN number is retrieved from its IMSI. Its PLMN number are the 5 or 6 first digits of its IMSI.

This way, you can determine which carrier owns that SIMCard.

On the other rand, the network tower also broadcast its PLMN.

This way, an device can search for its HOME network every time you reboot you device (or move to another location).

**HOME vs ROAMING**

Home situation is when PLMN Number from the simcard is the same of the current registered network.

Roaming is when the SIMCard has a different PLMN than the registered cell.

Of course, some carriers has more than one PLMN Number and phone should be considered HOME in those situations. But this is another story.

**Finally getSimOperator() and getNetworkOperator()**

`getSimOperator()` This method returns MCCMNC (PLMN) from SIMCard

`getNetworkOperator()` This method returns MCCMNC (PLMN) from current camped Carrier

**It is up to you**

Now, you know the difference between simcard and network operator. So, you have to decide how to block/allow your app.

- If you block by `getSimOperator()` you are blocking the simcards from a specific country. This way, regarless the registered cell, feature will remain blocked (even if the user is travelling to a country with the feature enabled).
- If you block by `getNetworkOperator()` you are blocking the feature in specific networks/Contries. This way, if the user which can use the app, may have issues when he travells to a country where the feature is blocked.

Comment: Marking as correct because clarified pretty well my doubts on the matter, thanks!